# Execute job every minute in Lumen

Tags: laravel, lumen

I created simple Job class which I can call with dispatch.
But I don't know how to do this forever every minute.
I also added to Kernel.php schedule this:

```
$schedule->call(function () 
    $job = (new \App\Jobs\SomeJob())->onQueue('cron');
    dispatch($job);
}
)->everyMinute();
```

But on run schedule:run command, job runs only once and schedule:run command stops execution.

Comment: you need to run the command using crontab

Answer (score 0):

According to your code you add a job to queue once, so it executes once. Read the doc example https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/scheduling#scheduling-queued-jobs
So your code should be:

```
$schedule->job(new \App\Jobs\SomeJob())->everyMinute();
```